# How to use Sublime Text 2 build when using rbenv?

Tags: sublimetext2, rbenv

I'm using `rbenv`, and when trying to use the build function inside Sublime Text 2 (`Cmd+B`) it tries to use the ruby and gems under `/Library/Ruby/Gems/`

How can I tell ST2 to use my rbenv rubies?

PS: I installed rbenv using [boxen](http://boxen.github.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out this. In order to configure rbenv in ST2 you need to go to *Browse Packages*, then select the *Ruby package*, and edit the file `Ruby.sublime-build` changing the `cmd` property, like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/path/to/your/ruby/shim", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

In my case, since I'm using boxen, the path was `/opt/boxen/rbenv/shims/ruby`, but in a standard rbenv installation it should be something like `/home/username/.rbenv/shims/ruby` in Linux or `/Users/username/.rbenv/shims/ruby` in OS X.

Comment: If you're having trouble finding the `Ruby.sublime-build` file you can use the [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) package to easily find/edit it.